# amCharts 4: display legend tooltip on truncated (with ellipsis) values only

Tags: tooltip, legend, truncate, amcharts4

I've enabled the legend on a **amCharts v4** chart with the following code but I have **issues with ellipsis**:

```js
// Add legend
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.legend.fontSize = 11;

// Truncate long labels (more than 160px)
chart.legend.labels.template.maxWidth = 160;
chart.legend.labels.template.truncate = true;
chart.legend.labels.template.fullWords = true;

// Set custom ellipsis as default one is not displayed correctly
chart.legend.labels.template.ellipsis = "...";

// Set tooltip content to name field
chart.legend.itemContainers.template.tooltipText = "{name}";
```

As you can see I had to set a **custom *ellipsis*** property because Firefox v76 displayed `€|` instead of `…` on the truncated legend labels. It happens even on the [sample on the amChart website](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/ZVwLYz) but, surprisingly, not if I open the same URL in a private tab... How can I fix that?

Then I would like to display the tooltip on the legend **only for truncated labels**. Adding an adapter:

```js
chart.legend.itemContainers.template.adapter.add("tooltipText", function(text, target) {
     // 'text' here contains the non-truncated string
    return "My modified " + text;
})
```

of course works, but how can I identify inside the adapter code if the label that I'm processing is truncated and clear the *text* variable? It doesn't make sense to display tooltips for non-truncated legend items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer about the **tooltip** adapter; this works:

```js
chart.legend.itemContainers.template.adapter.add("tooltipText", function(text, target) {
     if (!target.dataItem.label.isOversized) {
          // Legend label is NOT truncated, disable the tooltip
          return "";
     }

     // Legend label is truncated, display the tooltip
     return text;
})
```

Still I don't know why the ellipsis are not displayed correctly without setting the property...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the most ideal way but...

You get the text inside the adaptor callback.
You can add a text.length check like:

```
chart.legend.itemContainers.template.adapter.add("tooltipText", function(text, target) {
     // 'text' here contains the non-truncated string

    return text.length > someValyeBasedOnMaxwidth> ? "My modified " + text: "";
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but as the "truncation" is done by the amCharts logic, what you proposed it's not what I want. There has to be a way to either search for the ellipsis or, better, a property that tells if the label is truncated or not. Something like *isTruncated*.